# AngularJS $http cache expiration time

Tags: angularjs

Can you set an expiration time for Angular's $http default caching system ?
I would like that an URL stays in the cache for 1 minute, so that any requests made to it after 1 minute grabs fresh data from the server.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no way to set the expiration time. But you can do it manually. You have to access the $http cache:

```
var cache = $cacheFactory.get('$http');
```

and remove the url that is cached by:

```
cache.remove(theUrl);
```

See [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$cacheFactory) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

according to [this site](http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/angularjs-vs-browser-http-cache) here are the `$cacheFactory` specs

- **Storage** Javascript heap memory
- **Eviction algorithm** Least recently used (LRU)
- **Time-to-live** until page refresh
- **Support for revalidation** No
- **Requires cooperation of remote server** No

Answer (score 3):

Another Solution:

Use `$httpProvider` to hook the request.

```coffeescript
http_ttl_cache = {}  # save the last cache time
MyApp.config ['$httpProvider', ($httpProvider) ->
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push ['$cacheFactory', ($cacheFactory) ->
        request: (config) ->
            if config.params and config.params.__cache__
                config.cache = true

                N = config.params.__cache__
                delete config.params.__cache__

                if moment() - (http_ttl_cache[config.url] or 0) > 1000 * N     
                    cache = $cacheFactory.get('$http')                            
                    cache.remove(config.url)                                      
                    http_ttl_cache[config.url] = moment()
            return config
    ]
]
```

In your controller:

```coffeescript
# 600 is 600 seconds
$http.get("/api/books?limit=100", 
          {
               params: {'__cache__': 600, 'foo': 'bar'}
          }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

An **expiration time-based cache** implementation for AngularJS might look like this:

```
MyAngularApp.factory('cache', function($cacheFactory) {    
    const cache = $cacheFactory('expire-cache');

    function get(key, defaultValue = null, expire = null) {    
        let cached = cache.get(key);
        let expired = cached && cached.expire > 0 && cached.expire < performance.now() - cached.created;
       
        if (!cached || expired) {
            cached = {
                value: typeof (defaultValue) === 'function' ? defaultValue() : defaultValue,
                expire: expire,
                created: performance.now()
            }

            if (cache.value !== null && 
                cache.value !== undefined) {

                cache.put(key, cached);
            }
        }
        
        return cache.value;
    }

    return {
        get: get,
        remove: function remove(key) { cache.remove(key) },
        clear: function clear() { cache.removeAll() },
    };    
});
```

The possible method calls would be these:

```
read = cache.get('keyName1', 'my permanent value');
read = cache.get('keyName2', 'my static value for 5 secs', 5000);
read = cache.get('keyName3', () => 'my on time value for 5 secs', 5000);

cache.remove('keyName1'); /* Remove one */

cache.clear(); /* Remove all */
```