# Same $http.get request automatically trigger success callback before processing in second call

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm trying to build a simple hybrid app with Ionic Framework.

I want to create an inifite scroll system, so I have:

```
.controller('DiscoverCtrl', function (uris, $scope, $cordovaToast, $http, $ionicLoading, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, $ionicScrollDelegate, $ionicPopover, localStorage, $ionicPlatform, helpers) {
   var loadCircuits = function(page_to_load) {
        var page_to_load = page_to_load || 1
        $http.get(uris({pagination: true, per_page: 10, page: page_to_load}).circuits.discover, {timeout: 20000})
        .success(function(response, status, headers, config) {
            alert("success")
             angular.forEach(response.circuits, function (circuit) {
                $scope.cards.push(circuit);
                // console.log(circuit.description)
              });
             $scope.next_page = response.pagination.next_page;
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            $ionicLoading.hide();
            // called asynchronously if an error occurs
            // or server returns response with an error status.
             $cordovaToast.showLongBottom('Sory, request failed:' + status).then(function(success) {
                // success
              }, function (error) {
                // error
              });
        });
    }

    loadCircuits();

    // Load more data
    $scope.loadMoreData = function() {
        alert("loadMore")
        loadCircuits($scope.next_page);
    }
});
```

And:

```
<ion-infinite-scroll
  immediate-check="false"
  on-infinite="loadMoreData()"
  distance="1%">
 </ion-infinite-scroll>
```

But I'm facing the following issue:

The first time I call `loadCircuits()`, the `success` callback is triggered normally. The second time (meaning when we call `$scope.loadMoreData()`, the success callback is triggered before actually performing the $http.get request... And I don't understand why.

Angular Version: 1.4.3.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The response is cached as the parameters don't change, look for `cache: false` option for `$http`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS $http cache expiration time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165282/angularjs-http-cache-expiration-time)

Comment: check your code, your `$scope.next_page` probably doesn't update as you expect it

Comment: Thanks for your help @maurycy  . Adding `cache:false` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$http calls are cached if they are made for same url with same parameters, so in your case it is possible that parameters haven't changed, I'd consider logging the next page.

You can also enforce not to cache with

```
cache: false
```

In $http request config